# Не получается подключиться к своему серверу из глобальной сети, работает только в локальной

Tags: c#, tcp-ip, ddns

При подключении к серверу по локальной сети все работает правильно, но если ноутбук с клиентским приложением находится в другой сети, то подключение не происходит. Брандмауеры на обоих ноутбуках отключил, видимо проблема была не в них. В настройках роутера настроил DDNS, открыл нужный порт для подключения из WAN (сделал переадресацию на ноутбук с серверным приложением, и да, выделил для него статический IP). Провайдер предоставляет "белый" IP, не "серый". Ниже часть кода сервера для приема входящих подключений:

```
 // получаем адреса для запуска сокета
            IPEndPoint ipPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);

            
            while (true)
            {
                // создаем сокет
                Socket listenSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                try
                {
                    // связываем сокет с локальной точкой, по которой будем принимать данные
                    listenSocket.Bind(ipPoint);

                    // начинаем прослушивание
                    listenSocket.Listen(10);

                    Console.WriteLine("Сервер запущен. Ожидание подключений...");

                    while (true)
                    {
                        //Сообщение для ответа клиенту
                        string message = "ERROR";

                        //Номер команды и её параметры
                        string numberCommand = "";
                        string parameters = "";


                        Socket handler = listenSocket.Accept();
                        // получаем сообщение
                        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                        int bytes = 0; // количество полученных байтов
                        byte[] data = new byte[256]; // буфер для получаемых данных

                        do
                        {
                            bytes = handler.Receive(data);
                            builder.Append(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data, 0, bytes));
                        }
                        while (handler.Available > 0);

                        // отправляем ответ
                        data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(message);
                        handler.Send(data);

                        // закрываем сокет
                        handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                        handler.Close();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    listenSocket.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

Часть кода клиентского приложения для подключения к серверу:

```
 public static List<string> RecieveDataFromDB(string numberCommand, string parameters = "")
        {
            //Список значений, полученных от сервера
            List<string> values = new List<string>();

            try
            {
                //Создаем удаленную конечную точку сервера
                IPEndPoint ipPoint = new IPEndPoint(IP, port);

                //Определяем объект сокета, для подключения к серверу по удаленной конечной точке
                Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

                //Подключаемся к удаленному хосту
                socket.Connect(ipPoint);
                byte[] data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(numberCommand + parameters);
                socket.Send(data);

                // получаем ответ
                data = new byte[8192]; // буфер для ответа
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                int bytes = 0; // количество полученных байт
                    
                do
                {
                    bytes = socket.Receive(data, data.Length, 0);
                    builder.Append(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data, 0, bytes));
                }
                while (socket.Available > 0);

                /*Получаем данные от сервера в виде строки: value1~value2~...valueN~ 
                 Обрабатываем данную строку, чтобы разделить значения и добавить их в список*/
                string msg = builder.ToString();

                foreach (string value in msg.Split('~'))
                {
                    if(value != "") values.Add(value);
                }

                // закрываем сокет
                socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                socket.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Выводим сообщения об возникшем исключении
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            //Возвращаем список значений для дальнейших действий
            return values;
        }
```

[image: переадресация в роутере]
[image: DDNS в роутере]

Подскажите, где я совершаю ошибку: в коде одного из приложений или же в настройке DDNS? При подключении из WAN выдает ошибку "Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной...", то есть на моменте подключения (этот же код работает правильно, если оба ноутбука находятся в локальной сети)

Comment: Зачем вам DDNS если у вас белый, статичный IP? Используйте его и вперед. И да, "Внутренний IP" вашего компьютера, у вашего роутера по умолчанию динамичный, задайте ему конкретный IP.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ не вижу, где сказано что статический

Comment: DDNS IP верно резолвит? Полученный IP на удаленной машине должен соответствовать внешнему IP роутера на момент подключения.

Comment: @aepot Не так понял эту фразу: `выделил для него статический IP). Провайдер предоставляет "белый" IP, не "серый"`. В любом случае, для начала стоит пробовать по ip подключиться, а уж потом думать как его украсить и зафиксировать.